# Queries with include in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include

I have the following problem.  I need to do a massive query of table named professionals but I need to optimize the query  because for each professional  I call the associated tables.

But I have a problem with two associated tables: comments and tariffs.

**Comments:**

I need to call 3 comments for each professional.  I try with:

```
@professionals.includes(:comments).where(:comments => { type: 0 } ).last(3)
```

The problem the query only brings 3 professionals, not what I need, all the professionals  with only three comments where type be equal to zero.

And when I try:

```
@professionals.includes(:comments).where(:comments => { type: 0 } )
```

The result is only professionals with (all the) comments when I need all the professional with or without comments. But if the professional have comments I  only need the last three comments where the type be equals zero

**Tariffs:**

With tariffs I have a similar problem, in this case I need the last 4 tariffs for each professional.  I try  with:

```
@professionals.includes(:tariffs).last(4)
```

But only brings the last 4 professionals.

**Models:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :client
      belongs_to :professional

end

class Professionals < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :comment

end
```

Comment: I don't really get the problem with your second option. You include all relevant comments for all professionals, which is fine. If you want the last 3 for an individual professional you can call professional.comments.limit(3) or professional.last(3) when you loop over the professionals in your query. The first will return an ActiveRecord::Relation and the lst one an Array. Can you show where you want to use the last 3 comments per professional?

Comment: You would need to run a subquery in the `WHERE` clause which counts the number of comments.  However how to do this (and more importantly how to do this without killing performance) depends on which RBDMS you are using. `.last(3)` does not work since it applies a `LIMIT` to the entire query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use limit on the joining table in `ActiveRecord`. The `limit` is applied to the first relation, which in this case happens to be `@professionals`.

You have a few choices choices:

1. Preload all comments for each professional and limit them on output (reduces the number of queries needed but increases memory consumption since you are potentially preloading a lot of AR objects).
2. Lazy load the required number of comments (increases the number of queries by n+1, but reduces the potential memory consumption).
3. Write a custom query with raw SQL.

If you preload everything, then you don't have to change much. Just limit the number of comments white iterating through each `@professional`.

```
@professionals.each do |professional|
  @professional.comments.limit(3)
end
```

If you lazy load only what you need, then you would apply the `limit` scope to the comments relation.

```
@professionals.all
@professionals.each do |professional|
  @professional.comments.where(type: 0).limit(3)
end
```

Writing a custom query is a bit more complex. But you might find that it might be less performant depending on the number of joins you have to make, and how well indexed your table is.

I suggest you take approach two, and use query and fragment caching to improve performance. For example:

```
- cache @professionals do
  - @professionals.each do |professional|
    - cache professional do
      = professional.name
```

This approach will hit the database the first time, but after subsequent loads comments will be read from the cache, avoiding the DB hit. You can read more about caching in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).